# RegEx for a URL path that can just be a forward slash

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to validate a URL path.
I have come up with this:

```
^\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)?$
```

Which allows me the have `/` or `/moo` or a more complex `/products-123` but it doesn't allow me to use multiple forward slashes like `/blog/posts-123`.

Can someone help me with this?

Ideally it should be able to allow:

1. Just a forward slash for the home route
2. A forward slash followed by alphanumeric (with dashes)
3. Step 2 duplicated indefinitely
4. It should not allow any path to end with a forward slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex allows

- a **single slash**, or
- a **slash**, followed by **alphanumeric chars and dashes**, repeated 1 or multiple times:

```js
let urls = [
  '/',
  '/aaa-bbb',
  '/aaa-bbb/ccc',
  '/aaa-bbb/ccc/ddd',
  '/aaa-bbb/ccc/ddd/eee',
  '',  // empty
  '//double-slash',
  '/end-with-slash/',
];
let regex = /^(\/|(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)+)$/;
urls.forEach((url) => {
  let result = regex.test(url);
  console.log('"' + url + '"  ==> ' + result);
});
```

Result:

```
"/"  ==> true
"/aaa-bbb"  ==> true
"/aaa-bbb/ccc"  ==> true
"/aaa-bbb/ccc/ddd"  ==> true
"/aaa-bbb/ccc/ddd/eee"  ==> true
""  ==> false
"//double-slash"  ==> false
"/end-with-slash/"  ==> false
```

As you can see from the result, it guards against an empty url path, a url path with double slashes, and a url path ending in a slash.

Explanation of regex:

- `^(\/|(...)+)$` - expect a single slash, or a 1+ sequence in parenthesis
- `\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$` - sequence in parenthesis is a slash, followed by one or more chars of alphanumeric and dash

Answer (score 1):

To also match a single `/` and not ending with `/`, you can use

```
^/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/)*[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `/` Match a single `/`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/)*` Optionally repeat 1+ any of the listed followed by `/`
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` Match 1+ any of the listed
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pTtuka/1)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think I figured it out:

```
^\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+))?$
```

Comment: Does this support your needs? It looks like it does not match a single slash, and it only matches one or two `/some-thing` sequences, not multiple. See my answer that supports all your requirements as stated.